# When trying to publish my shiny app I get error "Paths should be to files within project directory"

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a project in the following working directory:

```
> getwd()
```

> [1] "C:/Users/mikeb/Documents/R/CourseRA R Projects/Capstone"

Everything on my shiny app runs fine when I click "Run". But when I try to publish, I get the error:

> Paths should be to files within the project directory.

My code is below:

```
library(shiny)
source("C:/Users/mikeb/Documents/R/CourseRA R Projects/Capstone/predictor.R")

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
        output$text <- renderText({
            paste(filter_text(get_pred(input$input_str)))
        })
    }
)
```

As you can see, I am clearly referencing the same directory for predictor.R as is the working directory.

I am clueless how to fix this. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing "C:/Users/mikeb/Documents/R/CourseRA R Projects/Capstone/predictor.R" with "predictor.R"

Comment: Here is what I get:


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4257
Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'predictor.R': No such file or directory
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
  53: file
  52: source
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection

Comment: Solved - I had the working directory as /Capstone but then within this created the ShinyApp, but of course the ShinyApp working directory is therefore within Capstone/ShinyApp. So I needed predictor.R to be in the same directory as the shiny app, then everything was fine.